# Unable to get external maven dependencies for Junit and Selenium in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, dependencies

[image: Dependency '''org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53''' not found]I'm not sure if the issue of not being able to sync the dependencies is to do with proxy or firewall.

I have been trying to make it work but no joy.

Is there any solution for someone in my situation?

I have, reinstall, imported project, run maven clean and install in cmd but still no dependency has been imported.

Message displays 'Dependency "org.seleniumhq.selenium-java:2.53.0" not found'

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer. The issue is indeed proxy and by adding those lines in the settings.xml between  with your/company proxy details it should work.

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>xx.xx.x.xxx</host>
    <port>1234</port>
    <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

In some instances you may need to add the username and password to make it work.

```
<username></username>
<password></password>
```